# How to use ImmutableJS's reduce function with an Immutable accumulator?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm trying to use ImmutableJS's reduce function like so:

```
const myChanges = data
  .getIn(['a', 'b']) // Immutable.List
  .reduce((accum, data) => {
    // console.log('accum', accum);
    // console.log('data', data); <--- an Immutable.Map
    accum.push(List([ data.get('id'), data.get('time') ]));
    return accum;
  }, List());
```

However, `accum` always console logs as an empty Immutable.List. My guess is that it's because List() can't be mutated, so each time `accum` is returning a new empty Immutable.List().

What I would like to get is a list of lists, where each of the inner lists (essentially a tuple) consists of `id` and `time`.

How can I get this to work? Do I need to use `withMutations`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In immutable all data are 'readonly'. When you call the push method it returns a **new object** with the changes.
For this code to work you need to return directly:

```
const myChanges = data.getIn(['a', 'b'])
    .reduce((accum, data) => {
        return accum.push(List([ data.get('id'), data.get('time') ]));
    }, List());
```

or you can store the result in a variable and return it

```
const myChanges = data.getIn(['a', 'b'])
    .reduce((accum, data) => {
        let result = accum.push(List([ data.get('id'), data.get('time') ]));
        return result;
    }, List());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you return the original `accum`, not the new value that includes the data. Remember that [`push`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/push) returns a new list, unlike a mutable JS `Array`!

```
const myChanges = data
  .getIn(['a', 'b'])
  .reduce((accum, d) => {
    return accum.push(List([ d.get('id'), d.get('time') ]));
  }, List());
```